# how to click on edit button in selenium webdriver if text display in <td>without link and edit button is exist in 2nd td

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am working in selenium webdriver. I have a scenario in which I have a table in which many rows and 2 columns are existing for example Username and Edit image.Username does not have link for editing on clicking edit image you can edit the user.Every tr we have 2 td. In First td user name and 2nd td edit img icon. There are number of users and I want to edit particular user in the list. I am not understanding how to click on that particular username. Every td have a class name which are same with multiple records but username is unique.How can click on edit image for particular user, can anybody guide me with example?

Comment: Read Post:http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It would be easier if you can Upload your HTML code.

Comment: Please read [ask]. Please provide the code you have tried and the execution result including any error messages, etc. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score 0):

It is simple , as you are saying username is unique, go with username. like

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[text()='your username']/following-sibling::td"));
```

so in the `xpath` I'm not referring to any class so u should get one match if you check this using firepath (firefox add on)

```
"//table/tbody/tr/td[text()='your username']/following-sibling::td"
```

here the following-sibling is your image associated with your username so, you should be able to perform your actions on it.

Comment: Hi Arun I have write code as below, but its not working  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@name='panel']//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[1][text()='TEST']//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/img")).click();;

Answer (score 0):

Manoj,

By looking at the xpath you are using i see there is a problem with that xpath. did u check that xpath is valid in xpath checker or in firebug?

if its possible paste the html code and the UI screenshot so that i can take a look at it and suggest you.

Comment: Thanks a lots  Arun .. Its working now..with  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table/tbody/tr/td[text()='TEST']/following-sibling::td/img")).click();

Comment: Cool! give a thumps Up

Comment: Hi Arun, I am facing a problem and ask question in the following link. Please help if u have answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020040/i-write-a-function-for-window-handling-but-its-not-working-in-selenium-webdriver