# I wrote a function for window handling but it's not working in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I am working on Selenium webdriver and I have write a function for window handling. I have written code for naukri.com popup handling. My scenario is to Open the naukri.com and without closing popup window. I want to switch main window and click on Login button.I have written the code and created a function. when I am running the script focus is going on main page and url is displayed as selected but I am not able to click on Login button. I am not understanding where the problem is.Please suggest me.

```
public static WebDriver fn_SetFocus_According_Title(WebDriver dObj, String arg_title)
    {
    Set<String> setcol_windowHandle=dObj.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator<String>itcol_handleval=setcol_windowHandle.iterator();

    while(itcol_handleval.hasNext()==true){
    String windowhanldval=itcol_handleval.next();
    dObj=dObj.switchTo().window(windowhanldval);
    String apptitle=dObj.getTitle();
        if(apptitle.contains(arg_title))
            {
            dObj=dObj.switchTo().window(arg_title);
            }
        }
      return dObj;
   }
}
WebDriver dObj = new FirefoxDriver();
    dObj.manage().window().maximize();
    dObj.get("https://www.naukri.com");
    dObj.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60,TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    dObj=fn_SetFocus_According_Title(dObj,"Jobs - Recruitment - Job Search - Employment - Job Vacancies - Naukri.com");
    dObj.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@id='login_Layer']")).click();
```

Comment: Try printing all the `apptitle` before the `if` method. Assuming your implementation is on the right path, I think it's the `if` method that has the bug. Because you are doing a `contains` check, and even an additional space character may be causing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the following changes in your code:

1. Change to:
   dObj.switchTo().window(windowhanldval);
2. Reduce the actual string of "arg_title" as you would be looking for this entire string within the String obtained by getTitle()
3. When you are already on that page trying to match the page title which means the focus is already on the actual page where we need to locate the Login button element. So remove the second switch () line entirely. Rather use "break" to come out if loop.

Let me know if these steps works for you.

Comment: Did my answer help you to overcome the problem you are facing?

Comment: HI dev,  Thanks for reply. I have just change in one line.according to your suggestion I have removed second switch () line entirely and used "break" to come out if loop.

Comment: @ManojKumar Great, Glad to be able to help you. Please upvote the Answer if you feel it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

The function below works for me.

```
public static void switchToWindow(String windowTitle)
{
    for (String window : driver.getWindowHandles())
    {
        driver.switchTo().window(window);
        if (driver.getTitle().equals(windowTitle))
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    throw new InvalidParameterException("The window titled <" + windowTitle + "> does not exist.");
}
```

One issue you may run into is that when a new tab/window is created, you may need to wait for it to appear. To do that, you can use something like

```
int count = driver.getWindowHandles().size() + 1; // add 1 to the current window count
// do something that spawns a new window
new WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(ExpectedConditions.numberOfWindowsToBe(count));
```

You don't need to return the `WebDriver` instance. It's the same driver instance you are already using. If the expected window title is not found, the function will throw an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will work for you.

```
public void Parenthandle(WebDriver wb){
    try {
        String ParentPageHandle = wb.getWindowHandle();
        for (String newPage : wb.getWindowHandles()) {
            if (!ParentPageHandle.equals(newPage)) {
                wb.switchTo().window(newPage);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }
```